# Implementing a template class Stack1

Tags: c++

The following link is a  picture that shows the skeleton of the class.

[image]

This is what i have so far what i wanna know is if what i'm doing is in the right direction.
I first Created a Template named ItemType then i created a class named Stack1.
inside Stack1 i had two private class members a ItemType pointer (info) and a integer (top) then i created a default constructor and assigned values to my class members and a copy constructor that take in a reference for a class object .

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>

class Stack1
{
 private:
    ItemType* info;
    int top;
 public:
    Stack1()
   {
    int MAXITEM = 5;
    top = -1;
    info = new int[MAXITEM];
   }
Stack1(const Stack1<ItemType> &x)
{
    int* copy;
    copy = new int[x.MAXITEM];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = x.info[i];
    }

}
void push(ItemType x)
{
    top++;
    info[top] = x;
}
void print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << info[i] << " " << endl;
    }
}

void MakeEmpty()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        info[top] = NULL;
        top--;
    }

}

};


 int main()
{
 Stack1 <int> X;
 X.push(2);
 X.push(5);
 X.push(8);
 X.push(7);
 X.push(10);
 X.print();w
 Stack1 <int> X2;
 X2 = X;
 X2.print();
 X.MakeEmpty();
 X.print();

}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming `ItemType` and `int` are *always* synonymous ? Kind fo defeats the purpose of a template, doesn't it ? `info = new int[MAXITEM];` for example. That should be `info = new ItemType[MAXITEM];`. Also, there is no `MAXITEM` member variable (static or otherwise), so no clue what you're hoping for with `copy = new int[x.MAXITEM];` .Regardless, you seem to have forgotten to ask a question is your post.

Comment: `info[top] = NULL;` is not what you should do to empty the array. `ItemType` may not  like to have `NULL` (or the prefered `nullptr`) assigned to it. For now, just reset `top` in `MakeEmpty`.